# how to use network flow to solve linear programming?

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, network-flow

suppose we are given m examination E={E1,E2,...,Em} and a set of instruments of I={I1,I2,...,In} and each examination Ej needs a subset of Rj of I. each examination has Pj $ profit and each instrument costs Cj $. we want to choose some examination to maximize (sum of profits - sum of costs).

I think we can use LP such that we have m variable Xi for each examination and Xi = 0 or 1 and our objective function is : for all i and j Xi(Pi) - (A)Cj where A is xor all Xi that need Ij

but i can't model this problem by network flow. my problem is how to represent the fact that when we choose an examination and pay for its instruments we can use those instruments for other examination.

Comment: Try to think of it in terms of minimum cuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model the problem as a bipartite graph: put the examinations as vertices on the left side and the instruments on the right side. Connect examinations to their instruments via edges of infinite capacity. Now introduce a source S and a sink T. Connect S to the examinations via edges that represent their profit. Connect the instruments to T via edges representing their cost.

The maximum profit is *sum of all Pi - min cut*.

Why? Think about cutting edges in the graph to separate T from S. For each examination, we need to cut either the examination itself, "paying" for the profit we missed, or all of its instruments.

An optimal set of examinations is represented by the set of examination vertices reachable from S in the residual flow network.

Comment: i can't understand why maximum profit is sum of all Pi - min cut. if optimal set of examinations are those reachable from S in residual flow network why we add profits of all examinations to final profit?

Comment: @amir Since minimum cut only works with non-negative weights, we model the problem such that doing examination i has cost 0 and not doing it has cost Pi. In reality though, we have cost -Pi for doing the examination and 0 for not doing it, so we need to subtract Pi from the min cut result.